# add jquery in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I have HTML like:

```
<select id="example">
<option value="1">Short</option>
<option value="2">Oh dear, this option has really long text :(</option>
```

I want to add following jquery into an angular controller, How can I do this?

```
 var maxLength = 15;
$('#example > option').text(function(i, text) {
    if (text.length > maxLength) {
        return text.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';
    }
});
```

Comment: sounds like a job for a directive! https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.  However, you really should consider trying to embrace the angular way of doing things, and not revert to jquery unless there is no other option.  There is a reason that angular functions without jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be doing it like that, that violates the way AngularJS is intended to work, and will frustrate any other AngularJS developers who look at your code.

Instead, change to declaring the list of options as a property of the scope in your controller, and modify the text there to truncate it to the length required.

e.g.

Markup:

```
<select id="example" ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in options">
```

Controller code:

```
var maxLength = 15;
$scope.options = ['Short', 'Oh dear, this option has really long text :('].map(function (text, i) {
  return {
    value: i + 1,
    text: text.length <= maxLength ? text : text.substring(0, maxLength) + '...'
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks.I'm really new to angular.How can I replace ['Short', 'Oh dear, this option has really long text :('] to dynamically pass the value in options?Cuz I cannot hard code it right?

Comment: I don't know. That depends on where you are getting your options from. Instead of the hardcoded array I used, just put the controller code I mentioned wherever you have access to an array of the strings you want to display.